# PC monitor USB hub backfeeding inro PC

Tags: monitor, usb-hub, pc

So I bought a Fujitsu P23T-6 Thor Edition a while back to use as a second monitor, it had an built in 2 port USB hub which I use for plugging in my keyboard and mouse.

Now yesterday I watched a video on how a USB hub that where backfeeding power to a Mac had killed the Mac. I remembered that when I've turned my computer off and also turned off the switch on the PSU the power indicating lights had still remained on on my grapicscards. That is until I unplug the USB cabled that comes from USB hub in my monitor...

Earlier today I tested my theory by plugging the cable into a USB fan using a female to female connector.

So my question is, could this have damaged my computer or at least cause problems, since I've experienced some 0,5 ms freezes for a while now
(Though there could be another reason for this).

Also what reason would they have to do this? Or is it just a design error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you damaged your computer -- it's more likely that you would have damaged that USB hub or its power supply. In the case you described, the hub probably had its own +5V USB supply that it connected to the V+ pins on both the downstream and upstream ports. When connected to your PC, the V+ pin on your PC USB's controller would have been tied directly to the +5V supply from the hub.

Most USB host ports implemented correctly include a current-limiting power-switch that serves to limit the supplied current to 500mA (classic) or higher (for faster charge ports). Chances are that when your PC is off, that switch is electrically off and the supplied +5V isn't actually going anywhere in the system.

Now, if that switch wasn't there, you'd be trying to power everything that normally runs off 5V from the USB hub's power supply, and that little guy would probably over-current and protect itself.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. Though would you recommend to keep using it? As you said that it probably doesn't damage the computer. Or would it be better to just get a new hub?

Comment: You could cut the hub's USB power line since it has it's own source. That way you'd be sure it won't damage the pc or vice versa.

Comment: @DELTA12 I could, but then I would have to dissemble the whole screen, anyone know if you can just buy a cable without the 5v wire? Otherwise I'll just get a new hub.

Comment: Probably easier to just buy a new hub. If you modded the cable, you'd have to make sure you always used that specific cable.